# php and mysql not activating new user after clicking email activation link

Tags: php, mysql

i am creating a registration/login system with php. my code is able to send an activation link to the new user via email, but wen user clicks on the link, user is not activated..pls can anyone help, the codes are below...

users.php

```
function activate($email, $email_code) {
    $email          = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
    $email_code     = mysql_real_escape_string($email_code);

    if (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `user` WHERE `email` = '$email' AND `email_code` = '$emal_code' AND `active` = 0"), 0) == 1) {
        if (mysql_query("UPDATE `user` SET `active` = 1 WHERE `email` = '$email'")){
         return true; 
    } else {
         return false;  
    }

}
}

function register_user ($register_data) {
    array_walk($register_data, 'array_sanitize');
    $register_data['password'] = md5($register_data['password']);

    $fields = '`' . implode('`, `', array_keys ($register_data)) . '`';
    $data   = '\'' . implode('\', \'', $register_data) . '\'';

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `user` ($fields) VALUES ($data)");
    email($register_data['email'], 'Activate your account', "Hello " .      $register_data['username'] . ",\n\nYou need to activate your account by clicking the link below:\n\nhttp://fredhosting.com/real/activate.php?email=" . $register_data['email'] . "&email_code=" . $register_data['email_code'] . "\n\n - Fredhosting.com");
}
```

Activate.php

```
if (isset($_GET['success']) === true && empty($_GET['success']) === true) {
?>
    <h2>Thanks, we have activated your account...</h2>
    <p>You can now Log in!</p>
<?php
} else if (isset($_GET['email'], $_GET['email_code']) === true) {

    $email       = trim($_GET['email']);
    $email_code  = trim($_GET['email_code']);

    if (email_exists($email) === false) {
        $errors[] = 'Oops, something went wrong and we could not find that email address.';
    } else if (activate($email, $email_code) === false) {
        $errors[] = 'We had some issues activating your account.';
    }

    if (empty($errors) === false) {
    ?>
        <h2>Oops...</h2>
    <?php
        echo output_errors($errors);
    } else {
        header('Location: activate.php?success');
        exit(); 
    }

}
```

Comment: Does your script produce an error or something?

Comment: Have you done any sort of debugging to narrow down the problem? My guess is that if you sprinkle some simple `var_dump()` statements in your code for debugging, you will find the problem right away.

Comment: Another pointer... in your `activate()` function there is absolutely no reason to first make a SELECT.  You can go directly to an UPDATE and remove the need for multiple queries IF you handle all the results/error conditions correctly (which you SHOULD be doing anyways).

Comment: hello guys...thanks for the reply...its actually not producing any errors at all, just doesnt activate new user.

Comment: @user2983998 Why is it not activating the user? At what point in the code execution does it not do what you are expecting?  Have you tried handling your errors in MySQL to see if there are problems there? Proper code should not just fire of requests against a database within inspecting the results to see if you are getting back what you expect. Also you should not even be writing new code at all using `mysql_*` functions, as they are deprecated.  It would be recommended to use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead.

Comment: You've got a typo in the SQL - `email_code = '$emal_code'`. You really need to check that your queries are working, and handle the results appropriately. `mysql_query` will return a boolean false if the query fails, but you're just using the output `mysql_result()`, assuming that it's succeeded.

Comment: In addition to problem @andrewsi points out, there are very obvious problems with your conditionals in activate.php.  It is actually quite impossible for any `$_GET` value to strictly compare to a boolean, as `$_GET` values always contain strings or arrays of strings.  Simple debugging would have revealed this.

Comment: thanks guys, i've found the problem, it was just a typo issue...kinda silly of me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error:

```
if (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM 
`user` WHERE `email` = '$email' 
AND `email_code` = '$emal_code' 
AND `active` = 0"), 0) == 1)
```

> incorrect variable $emal_code

Spelling errors are normally, however, before you post your code reread several times!

It seems that you are working with PHP errors turned off, activate recommend them.

```
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: hahhahahha i cnt believe dat was my error....am so very greatfull GOD bless u wherever u are...thanks